# Create leading zero in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers, leading-zero, adempiere

I am using `Adempiere` which has database `Oracle`

I have window called `Stock Code` from table called `M_StockCode`

The fields are `Code` and `Description`.

Currently, `Code` data type is `Number` and `Description` is `Varchar2`

I want to input `Sparepart` with `Code` `01`, and `Body Repair` with `Code` `02`.

As I input the data in Adempiere and save it, what will show is `Sparepart` with `Code` `1` (without leading zero)

I've tried putting `LPAD` function but it's still failed.

How can I put 01 both in Adempiere interface and in database?

Any suggestion will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **NUMBER** cannot have leading zero, a **STRING** can.

1. If you want to **store** the codes with **leading zero** in the database table, then you must use **VARCHAR2** and not **NUMBER**.
2. If you want to just **display the number** with leading zero, then use **TO_CHAR** to convert the number into string.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(1, '00') FROM DUAL;

TO_
---
 01
```

You could also use **LPAD**, but remember, the data type of the result would be a string and not a number.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT LPAD(1, 2, '0') FROM DUAL;

LP
--
01
```

Answer (score 0):

In Adempiere you manage the model via the [Application Dictionary](http://wiki.adempiere.net/Application_Dictionary), it's the equivalent of the Data Dictionary used by relational databases.

1. Login to Adempiere as the System Administrator.
2. Select menu option `Application Dictionary->Table & Column`.
3. Select the **M_StockCode** table and from its window, click on the *Columns* Tab.
4. Here, select the **Code** column and if need be toggle to the *Form* view
5. Now, from the drop-down select the *Reference* value of **String** and set a **Length** equal 2.
6. Finally, hit the `Synchronize Column` button to have Admepiere modify the database.

If this code is some kind of classification it might be useful to create new **Reference** type in the Application Dictionary and then you could point your column to it; this would ensure consistency, offering the user a selection to choose from rather than entering values.  A *[Reference](http://wiki.adempiere.net/Application_Dictionary#Reference)* can be a **List** type which is handy for short lists or **Table** driven which is useful when the classification is more volatile and needs to maintained by the users.